# Website publish XmlSerializers System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

We have a website that is composed of multiple projects, all of which are .NET 3.5.

Since moving to Visual Studio 2019 (albeit on a new Windows 10 machine) we can no longer publish this. We could using Visual Studio 2017.

So the behaviour is as follows:

1. compile in DEBUG mode. This compiles perfectly and site runs
2. compile in RELEASE mode. This compiles perfectly and site runs
3. attempt to publish, we get a compilation error.

FYI, the publish profile is as follows:

```
<Project ToolsVersion=“4.0” xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003”>
<PropertyGroup>
<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
<LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
<ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
<publishUrl>\OurUncPath</publishUrl>
<DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
<PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
<EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
<DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
<WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The compiler throw the error:

Could not load file or assembly ‘OneOfOurLibraries.XmlSerializers’ or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly ‘OneOfOurLibraries.XmlSerializers’ or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

We have checked everything that we can think of between the set-up of our old computers (with VS2017) and our new computers (with VS2019) and they appear to be identical…

Comment: What version of the runtime is being loaded by the exe failing to load the serialiser assembly?

Comment: Hi @Richard.  Not sure I fully understand.  This is an ASP.NET WebForms application, all addressing .NET 3.5 and hosted by IIS with AppPool using .NET 2.x.  In VS2019 it compiles fine, but when publishing we get this compilation error.  Please let me know what further details would help.

Comment: Is `OneOfOurLibraries.XmlSerializers` a prebuilt serialisation library, or created dynamically?

Comment: @Richard, the `OneOfOurLibraries.XmlSerialize` is build dynamically.